# Reading (x,y) value pairs from a json file python

Tags: python-3.x, geojson

I have a Geojson file which has some content like below:

```
[
  {
    "type": "MultiLineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          -118.223243,
          34.050979
        ],
        [
          -118.223138,
          34.050832
        ],
        [
          -118.223074,
          34.050732
        ],[
          -118.221781,
          34.035823
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
```

I have a python file which has to read the file, store the coordinates into a variable so I can use the information in that variable to plot lines using matplotlib

I have tried writing code to read the contents and getting lines but the coordinates seem off completely. Not getting the output expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import json

with open('response.json') as json_file:
m1 = json.load(json_file)


for i in m1:
    for j in i["coordinates"]:
        for k in j:
            for l in k:
                plt.plot(l)
plt.show()
```

Expected Result: Multiple lines should be plotted based on coordinates

Actual Result: Nothing happens. No lines being plotted at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would go through each pair of coordinates and store the points, then plot as x vs y. It's most likely more efficient/better practice to use something like numpy though:

```
points = {"x":[], "y":[]}
for data in m1:
    for coordinateList in data["coordinates"]:
        for coordinate in coordinateList:
            points["x"].append(coordinate[0])
            points["y"].append(coordinate[1])
plt.plot(points["x"],points["y"])
```

Comment: I added the new code. For some reason nothing gets plotted and appears my code is crashing

Comment: The code worked and I see multiple lines plotted on the same screen. Appears this is the expected output. Thank you Hussain